# Plot R, curve smooth

Tags: r, plot, smoothing, curve

In a plot with points, I also have some curves. I used the `curve` function to get the exponential function in:

```
curve (fishA$parameterB * (x ^ fishA$parameterAlpha), 
       from = 50, to = 80, n = 100, add = TRUE)
```

The curve isn't smooth. How do I improve it? Maybe smooth is not the right word, but the curve is not nice.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't give the paramter values, so I cannot reproduce your output. My guess is that you need to increase the value of n in the curve function call.

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar problem. I escaped just using excel to smooth the data and added the smoothed line to the dataframe in R.
Anyway, the panel.tskernelm (lattice extra) may help you.